# Is it possible to affect only one specific class without using ID when doing a DOM

Tags: javascript, css

like only apply a function to that specific class without needing to add id? like in css hover: there might be a lot of elements with the same class but only the one you hover would be changed, example

```
 function exp1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("port1");
    if (x.style.height === "60px") {
      x.style.height = "1000px";
      document.getElementById('ba1').src = "picnig/arrow2.png";
    }
      else {
      x.style.height = "60px";
      document.getElementById('ba1').src = "picnig/arrow1.png";
    }
  }
  function exp2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("port2");
    if (x.style.height === "60px") {
      x.style.height = "1000px";
      document.getElementById('ba2').src = "picnig/arrow2.png";
    }
      else {
      x.style.height = "60px";
      document.getElementById('ba2').src = "picnig/arrow1.png";
    }
  }
  function exp3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("port3");
    if (x.style.height === "60px") {
      x.style.height = "1000px";
      document.getElementById('ba3').src = "picnig/arrow2.png";
    }
      else {
      x.style.height = "60px";
      document.getElementById('ba3').src = "picnig/arrow1.png";
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to have some way of uniquely identifying the specific element. For example, if you know that it's the third element on the page you could do `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')` and then get the third item. Or if it has a child with a unique ID you could get the child element and then find its ancestor containing the class.

Comment: It depends on the dom relationship between "ba1", "port1" and whatever element "exp1" is a listener for.  Can you add some example html?

Comment: It might also be time to learn about [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which lets you find elements based on CSS selectors, which is far more versatile than just id, class, or tagname. (And on a modern JS note: don't use `var`, use `let` or `const`, and don't touch the `.style` property, instead add and remove classes using `.classList`. The only time you should be using `style` is if you're setting a CSS variable so that CSS can do the rest =)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to use store a key-value pair somewhere in the parent scope or in a `WeakMap`, add an event listener on the parent container and use `event.target` or pass `event.x, event.clientX, event.y, event.clientY` to `elementFromPoint` to grab the hovered element and then inspect `classList` property or `getAttribute("class", ...)` to verify if it is what you want.

But since you want to do it via css, here is one way, set a property on `:hover`, and check if that property value matches. Beware, you must throttle this function. Do not call it all the time since `getComputedStyle` is quiet taxing.

PS: give all your 'ba' elements a common class, set property on css hover. Like below

```js
const pool = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
function findTheHoveredElement () {
  return Array.from(pool).filter(d => +getComputedStyle(d).getPropertyValue("--x") === 1)
}

setInterval(function(){
  const selection = findTheHoveredElement();
  if(selection.length){
    console.log(`You are hovering on ${selection[0].textContent}`)
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
div.someclass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: magenta;
}

div.someclass:hover {
--x: 1;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">1</div>
<div class="someclass">2</div>
<div class="someclass">3</div>
```